# unable to install jquery Bundle for Aptana 3.0

Tags: jquery, git, aptana

I was trying to install jquery bundle and during installation power went off. I started the machine again and when I try to install I'm getting following error mesg.

```
jeyakumaran_m@3LG-DEV-207 ~/Aptana Rubles
$ git clone git://github.com/aptana/javascript-jquery.ruble.git
fatal: destination path 'javascript-jquery.ruble' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

has anyone else encountered this error? I re-installed Aptana even then no luck.

can someone help me out. Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are windows 7:

1. Remove the folder `'C:\Users\Administrator\Aptana Rubles\javascript-jquery.ruble'`, remember to replace `Administrator` with your username;
2. Re-install the the plugin `javascript-jquery`.